# ng-repeat to access array inside of objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array with a list of objects. Each object also including an array (see below). I am using ng-repeat to iterate through the child array for each object, I tried many different way, but it just don't work at all. Any hint, direction, help would be great appreciated.  Thank you. :-)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    angular.module('mlApp', [])
       .controller('mlCtrl', [function () {
          var self = this;
          self.contacts = [
            { contact: 'AAA', mlist: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1] },
            { contact: 'BBB', mlist: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] }

          ];
 } ]);

<div ng-app="mlApp" ng-controller="mlCtrl as mCtrl">
<table>
<thead>..</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="p in mCtrl.contacts">
        <th width="100px" >{{p.contact}}</th>
        <td ng-repeat="c1 in p.mlist"><input type="checkbox" ng-check='{{c1}}' /></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The hint is to check the console for [errors](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=c1%20in%20p.mlist&p1=number:0) - Angular is (usually) very helpful with such things.

You have duplicate values in your array you use in the inner ng-repeat, so you need to track it by something. I used $index in this example:

```js
angular.module('mlApp', [])
  .controller('mlCtrl', [
    function() {
      var self = this;
      self.contacts = [{
          contact: 'AAA',
          mlist: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
        }, {
          contact: 'BBB',
          mlist: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        }

      ];
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mlApp" ng-controller="mlCtrl as mCtrl">
  <table>
    <thead>..</thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="p in mCtrl.contacts">
        <th width="100px">{{p.contact}}</th>
        <td ng-repeat="c1 in p.mlist track by $index">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-check='{{c1}}' />
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It has to work! You're welcome. :) And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: NIce answer. @GeorgeHuang but if you are wondering why this does n't check the checkbox and update the values when you check or uncheck? you would need to tweak them a bit by doing `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="p.mlist[$index]" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-checked="c1===1"/>`  You need to use `ng-model` `ng-true/false-value` so that ng-model is set accordingly and ng-checked is only to fix the bug where truevalue/falsevalue does not know whether it is integer of string.

Comment: Hey PSL: For the checkbox to check.  Just do <input type="checkbox" ng-checked='{{c1}}' /> I added 'ed' in the end. That was an typo.  Thank you so much :-)

Comment: @GeorgeHuang for the checkbox to check that should be enough but it wont update the ng-model (Your original array), unless you are displaying readonly checkboxes. And even if you provide ng-model as you check and uncheck it will just set the value as true/false not 1/0 you would need ng-true/false-value for that. You can verify that by placing ` {{p.mlist[$index]}}` just above the checkboxes

Comment: Yes.!!  You are right.  I didn't think about this issue. Now I am facing it.  Thank you very much for reminding!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Same like that you can do this:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('mycontroller',['$scope',function($scope){
  
  $scope.students=[];
  var i=0;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    var item={Name:'',Marks:[]};
  
    item.Name='student' + i;  
    item.Marks.push({Maths:50-i,Science:50 +i});
    
    $scope.students.push(item);
  }

}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app='myApp'>
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body ng-controller='mycontroller'>
    <div ng-repeat='student in students'>
      Name : {{student.Name}} 
      <span ng-repeat="m in student.Marks">Maths:{{m.Maths}} Science:{{m.Science}}</span>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```